# Finding a vowel in a string

Tags: vb.net

I've given it a number of tries and while I can create code that will enable me to make it work for words such as "find" or "else" I'm unable to make it work for words starting with two or more consonants. My specific question would be is there a way I can make the program search for one of a,i,o,u, or e? so then I can request the position of the first instance of their use, using IndexOf + Substring to complete the question.

my code so far is :-

```
Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim word As String = CStr(txtInput.Text)
    Dim first_letter As String = word.Substring(0, 1)

    Const vovel As String = "aeiouy"
    Const constants As String = "bcdfjklmnopqrstvwxz"

    Dim find As String = word.Substring(0, vovel)
    Dim delete As String = word.Substring(vovel, constants)


    If vovel.Contains(first_letter) Then
        txtResults.Text = txtInput.Text & "way"
    ElseIf constants.Contains(first_letter) Then
        txtResults.Text = delete & find & "ay"



    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Any help or advice will be really appreciated

Comment: Are you aware that `letter` isn't declared and that `first_letter` is never used?

Comment: Once you've corrected your code you might find this useful: `If "aeiou".Contains(letter.ToLower()) Then`

Comment: I just tried it again, and posted my new code,

Comment: Still doesn't even compile; `.Substring()` doesn't accept string arguments!

Comment: FYI the word is "vowel"

Comment: What do you want with **Dim find As String = word.Substring(0, vovel)** and **Dim delete As String = word.Substring(vovel, constants)** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression such as `[aeiou]`.
Then use the `Index` property to get the location after matching

Answer (score 1):

If im understanding the question, you could use; e.g

```
    char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    string word = "test";

    var index = word.IndexOfAny(vowels);
```

Comment: But is case sensitive, also C# instead of VB.NET.

Comment: If it needs to be case sensitive:

`char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U' };`

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do, here's one way:

```
Private Function IgpayAtinlay(word As String) As String
    Dim vowels As String = "aeiou"
    Dim Upper As Boolean = False
    If Char.IsUpper(word(0)) Then Upper = True
    For I = 0 To word.Length - 1
        If vowels.Contains(word(I)) Then
            If I = 0 Then
                'If the vowel is the first letter add "way" to the end
                word = word + "way"
                Exit For
            Else
                'Otherwise we take the rest of the word starting at the vowel,
                'put the beginning letters on the end and add "ay"
                word = word.ToLower
                word = word.Substring(I) + word.Substring(0, I) + "ay"
                'If the first letter was upper case then make the new first letter
                'the same
                If Upper Then word = word(0).ToString.ToUpper + word.Substring(1)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return word
End Function

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    txtResults.Text = IgpayAtinlay(txtInput.Text)
End Sub
```

I included code to maintain the case of the first letter

TODO:

Use a list of words to validate the input to make sure it's a valid word.